# sessionStorage only storing one item, seemingly as a string

Tags: javascript, html

Weird issue (on Chrome, FWIW) with sessionStorage.

```
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('videoViewed')) {
    console.log('Playing video');
    sessionStorage.setItem('videoViewed', new Date());
    playVideo()
} else {
    console.info('Not displaying video; already played this session');
}
```

For some reason, it seems to store the date value as the key for an entry in sessionStorage with an empty value.

Am I having some sort of aneurysm and doing this wrongly?

Comment: When setItem to webstorage, you need to set a key and a value and it must be strings. Date is an object so you can use JSON.stringify but that's a built-in Object. You should get the date as a string better than stringifying Objects.

Comment: This is working perfect in Chrome What issue are you facing `sessionStorage.setItem('myDate', new Date());
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('myDate');
console.log(data);`

Comment: Just found this: [*...calling it as a regular function (i.e. without the new operator) will return a string rather than a Date object; unlike other JavaScript object types,*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax)